# Exclude default headers set by OkHttp library

Tags: android, okhttp

In recent versions of OkHttp library, headers like "Accept-Encoding" and "User-Agent" are added automatically if you don't provide them by yourself.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strip 'em with a [Network Interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).

```
client.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
  @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request()
        .newBuilder()
        .removeHeader("Accept-Encoding")
        .removeHeader("User-Agent")
        .build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
});
```

Comment: But how to be in situations when I manually set those headers?

Comment: Manually set 'em in the same interceptor? That's tough.